# Combination Lock (Java)

Tags: java, swing

I have a school assignment that i need to create. Below is the info:
Create a frame with ten buttons, labeled 0 through 9. To exit the program, the user must click on the correct three buttons in order, something like 7-3-5. If the wrong combination is used, the frame turns red.

I already finish the frame and the buttons with online research helps, but i just cant make the functionality to work. Please take a look at my codes and thanks in advance.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class ComboNumber extends JFrame implements ActionListener{

//variable declaration
int ans1 = 3;
int ans2 = 7;
int ans3 = 1;
int one, two, three;
String inData1, inData2, inData3;
JButton[] button;

//constructs the combolock object
public ComboNumber()
{
    //sets flowlayout
    getContentPane().setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    Container c = getContentPane();
    //creates buttons
    button = new JButton[10];
    for(int i = 0; i < button.length; ++i) {
        button[i] = new JButton("" + i);
        //adds buttons to the frame
        c.add(button[i]);
        //registers listeners with buttons
        button[i].addActionListener(this);
    }

    //sets commands for the buttons (useless)

    //sets title for frame
    setTitle("ComboLock");
}
//end combolock object

//listener object
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt)
{
   Object o = evt.getSource();
   for(int i = 0; i < button.length; ++i) {
       if(button[i] == o) {
           // it is button[i] that was cliked
           // act accordingly
           return;
       }
   }
}
//end listener object

//main method
public static void main (String[] args)
{
    //calls object to format window
ComboNumber frm = new ComboNumber();

    //WindowQuitter class to listen for window closing
    WindowQuitter wQuit = new WindowQuitter();
    frm.addWindowListener(wQuit);

    //sets window size and visibility
    frm.setSize(500, 500);
    frm.setVisible(true);
}
//end main method
}
//end main class

//window quitter class
class WindowQuitter extends WindowAdapter
{
//method to close the window
public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e)
{
    //exits the program when the window is closed
    System.exit(0);
}
//end method
}
//end class
```

Comment: What part of the functionality doesn't work? And what is the code where you have `act accordingly`?

Comment: you can set `breakpoints` and `debug` your code. It doesn't seem to be a complex thing.

Comment: I'd use `JToggledButton` instead.  Then you can simply check the selected state of the buttons as required.  Keep track of each button that is clicked and the value they represent.  If 3 buttons have been pressed check the values against your combination

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic idea is simple.

You need two things.

1. What the combination actually is
2. What the user has guessed

So.  You need to add two variables.  One contains the combination/secret, the other contains the guesses.

```
private String secret = "123";
private String guess = "";
```

This allows you to make the combination as long as you like ;)

Then in your `actionPerformed` method, you need to add the most recent button click to the guess, check it against the secret and see if they've made a good guess.  If the length of the guess passes the number of characters in the secret, you need to reset the guess.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
    Object o = evt.getSource();
    if (o instanceof JButton) {
        JButton btn = (JButton) o;
        guess += btn.getText();
        if (guess.equals(secret)) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Welcome Overloard Master");
            dispose();
        } else if (guess.length() >= 3) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "WRONG", "Wrong", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            guess = "";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This save time alot of time. I also learn a new lesson today. Again, Thank you